# WGET a Redmine CSV file

Tags: wget, redmine

I am trying to get a CSV file from Redmine in a shell script. WGET is complaining about an unacceptable. Any ideas what the magical incantation is, or how to find it?

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate --accept csv https://username:password@company.com/redmine/issues.csv?utf8=%E2%9C%93&columns=all&description=1
Resolving company.com (company.com)... 192.168.1.45
Connecting to company.com (company.com)|192.168.1.45|:443... connected.
WARNING: The certificate of ‘company.com’ is not trusted.
WARNING: The certificate of ‘company.com’ hasn't got a known issuer.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 406 Not Acceptable
2017-04-04 10:14:20 ERROR 406: Not Acceptable.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace --accept csv with --accept "*.csv". See the wget manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options

Comment: No luck. Note that I can request the URL in Firefox and the download dialog pops up. Is there anything else that I should be doing in the request?

Comment: Well you can try to remove the --accept csv. The --accept parameter forces the wget to only accept csv files. It does not seem to be necessary in this case.  Here is more information about the 406 error given by the wget command: https://httpstatuses.com/406